# Unknown database error on rails upgrade from rails 5.1.7 to rails 5.2.6 while running rails db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, upgrade

```
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:89:in `connect'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:89:in `initialize'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activerecord-5.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:22:in `new'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activerecord-5.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:22:in `mysql2_connection'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activerecord-5.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:874:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activerecord-5.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:853:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activerecord-5.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:814:in `acquire_connection'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activerecord-5.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:538:in `checkout'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activerecord-5.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:382:in `connection'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activerecord-5.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1033:in `retrieve_connection'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activerecord-5.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:118:in `retrieve_connection'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activerecord-5.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:90:in `connection'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/ar-octopus-0.10.2/lib/octopus/model.rb:159:in `connection_with_octopus'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activerecord-5.2.6/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:324:in `table_exists?'
(eval):2:in `strip_attributes'
/Desktop/platform/app/models/user.rb:234:in `<class:User>'
/Desktop/platform/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in `load'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in `block in load_file'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:661:in `new_constants_in'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:475:in `load_file'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:373:in `block in require_or_load'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:356:in `require_or_load'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `load_missing_constant'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:195:in `const_missing'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:542:in `load_missing_constant'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:195:in `const_missing'
/Desktop/platform/app/models/enterprise_api/v1/user.rb:2:in `<module:EnterpriseApi>'
/Desktop/platform/app/models/enterprise_api/v1/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in `load'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in `block in load_file'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:661:in `new_constants_in'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:475:in `load_file'
/Desktop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:373:in `block in require_or_load'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create => db:load_config => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.4.9'

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: It appears that your Rails application attempts to read from the database during startup (specifically in `app/models/user.rb:234`) which fails since the database does not exist yet. You probably have to change this part of your code so that data is only read after startup (e.g. using [initialization callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initialization-events)) or during an actual request.

Comment: Too late but one possible cause of your issue is https://stackoverflow.com/a/72191416/520567
My question seems to be a duplicate of yours but this can't be known for sure unless you try the solution. Anyway, hope this saves some hours of detective work for somebody.